# I want to find out how many Nios processors are on the board that I am linked with using JTAG, how to do this?

Tags: quartus, nios-ii

I just want to test how many Nios II exist inside the Qsys system and if they are in reset or executing code. Can this be done via the Nios II terminal?

Comment: NIOS2  is a soft-core in an Altera FPGA and is not visible on chain scan. You cn only see physical devices  (that is, FPGAs, ROMs and such) which are sitting on thee JTAG Daisy Chain.

Comment: When we use the eclipse IDE, it can find out how many Nios exist in the system (if any). I am sure there is something from commandline that can achieve the same objective.